# Probit function and standard deviation of difference function in R

Tags: r, diff, glm

I'm very new in R.

I'm currently working on analyzing labor force participation (LFP) of the single women with three or more kids in response to a tax credit schedule expansion for single women with three or more kids.

(*treatment group*: single women with three or more kids)

(*control group*: single women with two kids)

As LFP is a binary variable, I use a probit function and to isolate the effect of the tax credit expansion, I use a difference-in-difference approach.

To illustrate this with code,

```
probit_model <- glm(lfp ~ three_kids + post_expansion + I(three_kids * post_expansion), family=binomial(link = "probit"), data=Mcps_s)
summary(probit_2)
```

where `three_kids` is a binary variable and equals one if the person i has three or more kids and zero otherwise; `post_expansion` is a binary variable and equals one if it's the time period after the expansion of tax credit.

Now what I'm interested in is that I want to get differenc-in-difference estimates and its standard deviation.

So I use `predict()` function and `diff()` function:

```
treat_prediction <- predict(probit_model,
                            newdata = data.frame("three_kids" = 1,
                                                 "post_expansion" = c(0, 1),
                                                 type = "response"))

diff(treat_prediction)
```

which gives me a value of 0.0216.

But how can I find the standard deviation of it?

And please let me know if you spot any mistake I made.

Thanks for reading my messed up writing.

Comment: have you tried adding `se.fit=TRUE` to your `predict` call?

Comment: you can just use the coeffcients for post_expansion, if i get you correctly, you are interested in the error associated with 1 unit change of your coefficient.  exp(coefficent of post_expansion) should give you back 0.0216 and summary(probit_model) will tell you the standard error of this estimate..

Comment: Thank you very much @StupidWolf !   Additionally, if I want to evaluate the difference-in-difference between treatment and control group, is it exactly the coefficient of  the interaction term between "three_kids" and "post_expansion"? and its std. error appears in summary(probit_model)?